# Option under LDAP Directory Search to search ROLE

Tags: pingfederate

Is there any option under LDAP Directory Search to search ROLE in LDAP. I am using Ping federate version 7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PingFederate LDAP data sources can be configured for Active Directory, PingDirectory, OpenLDAP, etc.  Since each user repository maintains roles differently the key is to configure the attribute that contains the roles.  In the LDAP Directory Search screen when configuring a connection you need to configure the attribute that contains all the roles, for example Active Directory roles are maintained in the memberOf attribute.  When a role is needed in fulfillment (e.g. SAML attribute fulfillment), the source to select is the LDAP along with an expression, be sure to [Enable OGNL Expression](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF/Enabling+and+Disabling+Expressions).  OGNL expressions allow you to search the result of the memberOf attribute for a specific role (e.g. security group).  There is a nice [blog series for OGNL expressions](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/blog/2013/06/05/introduction_to_ognl.html) on the Ping website that will help you with writing the appropriate expression.

Comment: Hi @Eric U. that helps me . Thanks for the information.

Comment: @MudassirTambe - you should mark Eric's response as an answer, unless it wasn't sufficient.

Comment: @AndrewK. yes it did answer my query .